# Conditionally execute a macro depending on the font used

Tags: latex, xetex

I’m a big fan of ampersands – so much that I heed SimpleBits’ advice to [“use the best available ampersand”](http://simplebits.com/notebook/2008/08/14/ampersands-2/) quite religiously.

For that purpose, I’ve defined the following shortcut in LaTeX:

```
\let\amp\&
\renewcommand\&{{\scalebox{1.2}{\textnormal{\fontspec{Baskerville}\itshape\amp}}}}
```

In brief, this changes all uses of the “normal” ampersand to a stylish variant, e.g.:

```
This is a text \& it contains an ampersand.
```

(Using `\&` instead of just `&` since that’s how LaTeX works – the latter is already reserved to separate columns in table environments.)

However, this always uses the same font – here, Baskerville – no matter whether it fits or not. I’d like to use a different font depending on the font family used. That is, I want to use another ampersand in combination with sans serif text, and in particular I want to *prevent* rewriting of the ampersand in a monospace context. So in the following two contexts, I don’t want to trigger the above definition:

```
{\sffamily a \& b}
{\ttfamily a \& b}
```

How do I do that?

I imagine something like the following:

```
\renewcommand\&{
  \ifsans
    {\fontspec{Trebuchet MS}{\textnormal{\itshape\amp}}}
  \else
    \ifmono
      \amp
    \else
      {\fontspec{Baskerville}\scalebox{1.2}{\textnormal{\itshape\amp}}}
    \fi
  \fi}
```

Comment: As a font-nerdery aside, I wish I knew how to make "&c" into a nice ligature.  It would help refute the perception that &c is a lazy shorthand for etc.

Comment: @Charles: As far as I know, there aren’t any common ligatures for that. But for Hoefler Text, `{\itshape{\addfontfeature{Alternate=3}\&}\kern-0.3ex{\footnotesize c}}` works quite nicely (although it’s extravagant) and for Trebuchet MS, try `\&\kern-0.3ex{\footnotesize c}` – I like it, even though the space between the `t` and the `c` is a bit too small and it’s not a real ligature.

Comment: Konrad: Just saw your not-very-recent tex.sx qn, [Replace et al. ...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/175) - a bit of "lazy shorthand" sentiment there, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works the following way:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}
\newcommand*\origsffamily{}
\let\origsffamily\sffamily
\renewcommand*\sffamily{\origsffamily\small {\renewcommand\&{{\scalebox{1.2}{\textnormal{\fontspec{Baskerville}\itshape\amp}}}}}}

\begin{document}


hello, this is \& a \sffamily test \& 


\end{document}
```

That means, you include the change of the ampersand sign into the definition of  (in my example) `\sffamily`.

The drawback is - of course - that you have to do this for all desired font families.

Comment: Amazing. Sooo easy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can test for the standard LaTeX token list `\f@family`, however, this might not be as reliable as you want. The following code simply checks whether the current family equals the default families set by `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`, but not whether the fonts are really sans-serif:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \amp { } {
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \f@family \rmdefault {
    % this is a roman font
    A
  } {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \f@family \sfdefault {
      % this is a sans font
      B
    } {
      % something else
      C
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

test \amp\ test

\sffamily
test \amp\ test

\ttfamily
test \amp\ test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Huh, habe noch gar nicht bemerkt, dass Du Dich hier auch rumtreibst … ;-)